# Angular 4 Component to Component Communication

Tags: angular, eventemitter, subscribe

I'm sending an API call on app.component.ts and emitting the change, so i can get the emitted value in the in the child components. Everything is working fine until a router redirect comes. After the router redirects the data is not rendering since it is not emitted. I believe this is because there is no change detected. when i refresh the page data is available. Is there any workaround to get the data.

**app.component.ts**

```
  ngOnInit() {
      this._ApiConnectorService.getQuestions().subscribe(res => {
      this._EmittersService.sendQuestion(res) })
  }
 }
```

**summary.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
   this._EmittersService.qustionEmitted$.subscribe(obj => {
     this.questionSummary = obj;
  }
}
```

**Emitter Function**

```
private emitQuestion = new Subject<any>();
qustionEmitted$ = this.emitQuestion.asObservable();
sendQuestion(change: any) {
  this.emitQuestion.next(change);
}
```

I'm calling the summary component via button click.

```
<button *ngIf="allAnswered" class="btn btn-view-summary" routerLink="/summary">  
  View Summary
</button>
```

Please guide me on this

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is inside your `_EmittersService.sendQuestion` method ?

Comment: Why don't you subscribe to ApiConnector inside EmitterService itself?

Comment: @Faisal
added the emitter function in the question

Comment: @wostex: I wanted to get the question only when the app loads, not sure though whether that's the correct approach

Comment: Can you describe more on how the router redirect behave on your app?